# Export child components and use individually

Tags: react-native

I have a case where I need to export two child components and use individually.

Much Desired outcome (Extremely simplified):

Controls.js:

```
const Controller = ( props ) => {

   const ControlBoxes = () => {
      return(<Button>Move around!</Button>)
    }

   const MoveableBox = () => {
      return(<View>I will be moved! </View>)
    }

   return {ControlBoxes, MoveableBox}
}

export default Builder
```

Canvas.js:

```
import Controller from './controls'

const boxScaleMove = boxes.map((box, index) =>  {
   return (
      <Bulilder.MoveableBox key={box.id} box={box}/>
   )
 }    


const boxController = boxes.map((box, index) =>  {
   return (
      <Bulilder.ControlBoxes key={box.id} box={box}/>
   )
 }   


return (
  ...
  {boxController}
  ...
  ...
  {boxScaleMove}
  ...
)
```

Any idea how I can achieve this or am I missing something fundamental? The main issue is that I want to avoid resorting to `useContext` (due to performance reasons in the case of a lot of boxes rendered) and be able to share variables and states between `MoveableBox`-component and `ControlBoxes`-component via `Controller` -parent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the compound component and use a lower level context to avoid re-rendering of the whole tree and share states across your components that way, below I would ilustrate a basic example of how that would work.

```
const RandomContext = createContext();

export default function Controller({children, ...rest}) {
  const [randomState, setRandom] = useState(0);

  return (
    <RandomContext.Provider value={{ randomState, setRandom }}>
      <div {...rest}>{children}</div>
    </RandomContext.Provider>
  );
}

Controller.ControlBoxes = function (props) {
  const { setRnadom } = useContext(RandomContext);

  return (
    <Button onClick={() => setRandom(2)} {...props}>Move around!</Button>
  );
};

Controller.MoveableBox = function (props) {
  const { randomState } = useContext(RandomContext);

  return randomState ? <View {...props}>I will be moved!</View> : null;
};
```

And you would use it as:

```
<Controller>
  <Controller.ControlBoxes />
  <Controller.MoveableBox />
<Controller>
```

In the compound components pattern we are leveraging the fact that in javascript when you declare a function you create a function/object combo. Therefor `Controller` function is both a function and an object, so we can assign properties the the object part of that combo, properties which are in our case `ControlBoxes` and `MoveableBox` which are functions themselves.

***NOTE*** you should probably assign named function the the properties of that object, it's easier to debug if the case needed.

```
Example.Function = function ExampleFunction(props) {
  return "Example";
};
```

Comment: This doesn't really work for me as I need to be able to use <Controller.ControlBoxes/> and <Controller.MoveableBox/> completely separate. Right now, state is only updated if I use them nested inside <Controller></Controller> like your example shows.

Comment: Depending on your use case you could move the <Controller /> one level up to the point in which you wrap both your childrens, and use it's childrens separately in different areas. The whole idea is that if you want to share states, you always need to have a parent that holds that state for all children components